# Run more than one endless loop script from /etc/rc.local

Tags: scripts, nodejs

I wanna run 3 endless loop scripts when starting up the system my idea dont works:

```
##!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
cd /
cd home
cd pi
cd steamidle
node lostkiko1.js &
node lostkiko2.js &
node d.js

exit 0
```

It just runs the first script (if any). I think the reason for that is clear: it stucks in the first because it is endless...
I have no idea how to fix that. Anyone has?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `cd` it's redundant. Use full path like `node /home/pi/steamidle/lostkiko1.js &` Also , your last script should also  end with `&` , because shell keeps waiting for your `rc.local` to exit, so it blocks other processes.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a separate entry for each script in the "Startup Applications" application.

Press the Super key to bring up the Dash search and search for "Startup Applications". There an entry can be added for each of the scripts. For example, for the first command, add "node /home/pi/steamidle/lostkiko1.js" as the command.